# All sub-menus are showing up on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to only show the sub-menu that is the child of the clicked li and button when it is clicked. Currently the click and show and hide are working but the code below shows both the sub-menus on click, I want only the child sub-menu of the li button to show on click.

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu link</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="link1.htm">link1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="link2.htm">link1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Menu link 2</a>
    <button aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle"></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="link1.htm">link1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="link2.htm">link1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="site-content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#menu-main-menu").on('click', 'button', function (event) {
        $('ul.sub-menu').appendTo('.site-content');
        if($('ul.sub-menu:visible').length)
          $('ul.sub-menu').hide();
        else
          $('ul.sub-menu').show();
    });
  });
```

CSS:

```
#menu-main-menu ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200000;
    top: 0;
    left: 1.5%;
    right: 1.5%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 9px;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.sub-menu .toggled-on {
    display: block;
}
.site-content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Solution:** So the solution here was to not use appendTo(), as I had to put the element back where it came from when toggled off. The solution was to merely toggle the menu item using correct position: absolute CSS for the .sub-menu and $()on('click' to toggle it.

```
   jQuery('#menu-main-menu').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
      if($(this).closest("li.menu-item").children("ul.sub-menu").length > 0)
    {
      $(this).closest("li.menu-item").children("ul.sub-menu").slideToggle('fast');
      return false;
    }
   });
```

Comment: You're missing curly brackets `{}` for your `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu that's purely stylistic.

Comment: Ah, didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisYongchu that part works fine

Comment: Your biggest problem here is appending, and suggested answers will not work completely - because: if you append closest  submenu to site content, it is removed from parent li, so you can't target it anymore (on second click) - try to do this without appending, and target submenus with using custom data attributes....

Comment: @nevermind I tend to agree, I have them clicking open individually now but not toggling closed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/abdqt6d9/

The problem is that you are writing incorrect selectors for your jquery:

```
$('ul.sub-menu')
```

That means it will grab all matching elements within the page.

What you need to do is grab the corresponding li. Within your click(), the $(this) becomes the button that is clicked. Using .parent() will give you the li element. From there, search for your corresponding sub-menus within the li_element:

```
var $li_element = $(this).parent()
var $sub_menu = $li_element.find(".sub-menu")
if ($li_element.find(".sub-menu:visible").length > 0) {
    $sub_menu.hide()
} else {
    $sub_menu.show()
}
```

The other problem is that perhaps your styling for your sub-menu is above the buttons. so once you show it, you can no longer press the button. So you need to restyle your sub-menus.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't show the sub-menu at all

Comment: $sub-menu  hyphen throws an error so I removed this

Comment: it does for me. perhaps  your styled sub menu is above your buttons? See my js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abdqt6d9/

Comment: Only the button toggles the sub-menu how to get the link to toggle the menu too?

Comment: please apply this answer to the links as well. i can't do all the work for you.

Comment: @ Hieu Le your fiddle works fine but I am appending the sub-menu to site-content it toggles open individually now but does not toggle closed again because it has been removed from the parent li so there is nothing there. Your answer is thus incomplete.

Comment: Like what @nevermind said, your appending to site-content is messing it up. Not sure why you are doing it that way. Please explain your reasoning and what you are hoping to accomplish with the appending part. Are you going to remove the submenu from the site-content again?

Answer (score 1):

`$("ul.sub-menu")` will apply to all the sub-menus, so you need to change it to only look for the sub-menu within the buttons parent. You can do this using [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) (or just [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent)) and then [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find)

```
//closest("li") will find the closest parent that is an li
//find(".sub-menu") will find the sub-menu within
$(this).closest("li").find(".sub-menu").show();
```

If you your button is always going to be before the sub-menu you can slim it down to just [.next(".sub-menu")](http://api.jquery.com/next)

```
$(this).next(".sub-menu").show();
```

Comment: Really not sure how to implement this in the code I have above

Comment: @Grant, replace each `$('ul.sub-menu')` with the code shown

Comment: Thanks, your answer did solve the problem of selecting the parent element correctly but my approach of appendTo() was not the way to go. I ended up using CSS to correctly place the sub-menu position:absolute where I needed it.